# extract solution given by solveset with complement

Tags: sympy

The solution given by solveset is in the following form

> {A}\{B}

How can I assign A to a new variable?

For example

```
solveset((x-y)/(x-t),x,domain=S.Reals)
```

returns R intersects with {y}\{t}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should literally do what you ask, but your intentions are not that clear. Is this what you mean?

```
>>> complement = solveset((x-y)/(x-t),x,domain=S.Reals)
>>> f, c = complement.args
>>> new_var = f.args[1].args[0]; new_var
y
```

If you mean that you don't want it showing as an intersection with R then declare y to be real: `y = symbols('y', real=True)`. In that case you will just get a FiniteSet as the first argument of the complement instead of a Union.